# 'of' or 'by' or 'from'

Tags: prepositions

I have a sentence that contains the phrase

```
We support products of different manufacturers [...]
```

Is the use of 'of' correct there? A coworker said I should use 'by' and I also can think of 'from' as a possible word.

When do I use which?

Comment: The most idiomatic preposition would be "*from*".  You might also find our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) a useful resource for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I wasn't aware that there is another SE about english language questions.

Comment: No problem Jens.  Yeah, we're trying to work on increasing the visibility of ELL; the good news is it's about to "graduate" out of (2 year long!) beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it must be just one word, then "from" is best.

"By" would only work if you change it to *we support products **made** by different manufacturers.

"Of" in this context sounds unnatural at least in AmE. Part of this is that "of" in that particular position (but not in this sentence) could reflect either a subjective or an objective genitive. Meaning it could mean either *We support the products that **come from** different manufacturers* or *We support the products that **belong to** different manufacturers.